# $A_5$ as a unique homomorphic image

Tags: group-theory

Is there an infinite group whose only (nontrivial) finite homomorphic image is $A_5$ (the alternating group of degree $5$) ?

**Edit**: I am interested in a group that is not the direct product of $A_5$ and an infinite group without finite quotients.

Comment: if you can explain the origin of this question or some motivation, I would think it would be easy for others to work in that way.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik - I disagree.  The question is very simple, and I doubt that any bit of motivation could make it clearer in any way.

Comment: @Donkey_2009: Of course the question is very clear as it is. But knowing the context and motivation of a question is often crucial to finding a solution.

Comment: The question is crystal clear, yet the reasons/motivations/background behind it aren't.

Comment: As for the answer to the question: I don't know but I highly doubt it. Such an infinite group would have to be virtually simple **and** precisely with one single **normal** subgroup of *precisely* index $\,5\,$...

Comment: @Donkey_2009 : Do not consider my statement as in any way "trying to discourage" the OP. I understand the question but unless i see some motivation, I personally could not try anything or else i might say the same thing whatever the OP know.

Comment: Try something like $\Bbb Q\times A_5$ ($\Bbb Q$ has non non-trivial finite quotients) and try to show that $\Bbb Q\times \{1\}$ is contained in the kernel of every homomorphism with finite image (e.g. by using Lagrange).

Comment: As another example, take the direct product of $A_5$ with any infinite simple group. It would be more interesting to ask if there was an example that does not have $A_5$ as a direct factor.

Comment: Thanks @ walcher and @Derek. I actually did not want $A_5$ to be a direct factor and edited the question accordingly.

Comment: The semidirect product $S\leftthreetimes A_5$ of an infinite simple $S$ group with an automorphism group isomorphic to $A_5$ would do. But I do not know if such an $S$ exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the following will work. Let $M$ be an irreducible module for $A_5$ over ${\mathbb Q}$. For example, we could take $M = {\mathbb Q}^4$ to be the 4-dimensional deleted permutation module. Now let $G = M \rtimes A_5$ with the module action of $A_5$ on $M$.